# Differences between iPhone OS v2 and v4?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

Can any one say difference between the iPhone OS 2+ till 4 and what's the main difference in the OS as well as the development in xcode..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the difference between the versions go to http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Release%20Notes and see the Documents called iOS x.x API Diffs

Comment: Thanks toncion,like wise do u hav any frame work or any sample for calling the soap webservice...

Comment: There's no builtin support in iOS for SOAP, but i would suggest using StackOverflows search function!!

Answer (score 1):

In [Release notes](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Release%20Notes) section of iOS Reference Library you can find "API diffs" docs for every iOS version starting from 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of this question should be very much in detail but may be following my answer in other post will help you to understand how apple world is working:

[Are there any Hardware Requirements to test iPhone Apps on your iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324989/are-there-any-hardware-requirements-to-test-iphone-apps-on-your-iphone/3325764#3325764)