# Is there an Apple document listing the differences between each version of the iOS SDK? (e.g. differences between iOS 3 and iOS 4)

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

Is there an Apple document listing the differences between each version of the iOS SDK? (e.g. differences between iOS 3 and iOS 4).

If not, how do other iOS developers keep up to date with the latest features without having to search through lots of documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differences between iPhone OS v2 and v4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317967/differences-between-iphone-os-v2-and-v4)

Comment: However, this newer question is worded much better and is an easier search target.

Answer (score 11):

For each new release of the SDK, Apple publishes three documents:

1. [What's New in iOS x.x](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iOS4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010313-SW1), giving a high-level overview of the new features.
2. [iOS SDK x.x Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-4_2/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010243), mentioning known issues and bugs.
3. [iOS x.x API Diffs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/iOS42APIDiffs/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010312), listing every single (documented) change in the APIs.